# SQLite, Many to many relations

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Student" (
"Student_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , 
"First_Name" CHAR, "Last_Name" CHAR, "Course" CHAR, 
"Year" INTEGER, "Semester" INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE "AddBook" ("Book_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , 
"Name" CHAR, "Edition" INTEGER, "Publisher" CHAR, "Price" INTEGER,
 "Page" INTEGER)
```

I'm making g a table for borrowing books name Issue and i put in it the "Student_ID" and "Book_ID" and the date of borrowing this is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Issue" ("Student_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"Book_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,"Date" INTEGER DEFAULT (null) )
```

how to show any borrowed books by but showing the all the  student info and all of the book info and the date

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT s.*, b.*, i.date
FROM Issue I
INNER JOIN Student s ON (i.Student_ID = s.Student_ID)
INNER JOIN AddBook b ON (i.Book_ID = b.Book_ID)
```

`INNER JOIN` will find the match student and the match book of your Issue table using the ID that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [join](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause) the three tables together:

```
SELECT *
FROM Issue
JOIN Student USING (Student_ID)
JOIN AddBook USING (Book_ID);
```